# PTIJ: Should we say "nes gadol haya po" in the synagogue?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud says:

> It is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Elazar HaKappar says: In the future, the synagogues and the study halls in Babylonia will be transported and reestablished in Eretz Yisrael. [Megillah 29a]

From this passage the Maharsha concludes that synagogues are considered parts of Eretz Yisrael (and so benefit from the blessings in Deut 11:18-21).  Just as embassies throughout the world are considered part of the represented country.

So, on Hanukkah, should we say "nes gadol haya po" in the synagogue?  (A great miracle happened *here* -- not *there* (sham).)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Whats the nafka mina?

Comment: @Shlomy The letters on the four battim of the dreidel are a הלכה למשה מסיני